# Why my code isnt working?

Tags: javascript, draggable, appendchild

I have a button. You can `appendChild` a draggable div, but it doesn't work.
 Can anybody help me please?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/no2o9vo4/1/

```js
var diva = document.getElementById("div-a");

function adddiv() {
 var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
 newdiv.className = "babydiv";
 
 diva.appendChild(newdiv);
}


function divMove(e){
   this.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
   this.style.left = e.clientX  + 'px';
}
```

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

#div-a {
 position: relative;
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: red;
}

.babydiv {
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 position: relative;
 width: 300px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="div-a">
 <div class="babydiv" onmousedown="divMove();">
   
   
 </div>
</div>
  
<a onclick="adddiv()">add div</a>
```

Comment: "divb is not defined"...you have declared `diva` but not `divb`

Comment: oh, i would type "this" divb wasnt the right, thx. Then there a any problem too.

Comment: Sorry I could not understand, has that solved your problem? Also note that your fiddle is not working as you have no included your JS script in your HTML

Comment: The Problem isnt solved. Its not because the script link. Its because the Script it self :(

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting? Please provide an logs that are in the console

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'top' of undefined... Cant fix it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldnt using the coordinates of the event only represent the coordinates when the event (mousedown) happened? Meaning you cant move it.

I guess you would have to have something select the target on `mousedown`, and then add an event listener for `mousemove`, changing the coordinates of the target as the mouse moves, and stop listening for the mousemove event when `mouseup` is fired.

I made a quick demo of my point here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ymqycx0e/

Hope this helps.

Comment: This Helps a lot. Thanks. But i have stil a problem. I cant appendchild more divs..